# Can I share also on "Enginnering Beta" a question posted on "Aviation", in order to share more persons?

Tags: discussion

Excuse, may I share the following question also on "Engineering beta" in order to share more persons about the problem?

[About climb: If we use T/W as input, the second grade equation yields two solutions for W/S. Are both solutions realistic?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27369/about-climb-if-we-use-t-w-as-input-the-second-grade-equation-yields-two-soluti/27403#27403)

Answer (score 6):

No, posting the same question on multiple sites is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/257476). It's better to have one question and to keep all of the answers in one place. You do have the following options:

1. Put a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question to draw attention to it.
2. Flag your question for migration to another site, if you feel it would fit better and get better answers there. A moderator will then decide if it should be migrated.
3. Ask a different question, maybe more specific, based on the answers to your first question.
4. Post your question in the chat of another site where users might be interested.

In the case of your question, it seems closely related to aviation and the answer you currently have seems thorough. I'm not sure that the general Engineering site would yield better answers. They have similar traffic but on topics that are much more varied. They also aren't as active in their chat, so that option may not be very effective either. It looks like you've added a second related question; you might want to post that separately, even though it is closely related.